# Facebook API only working when I'm logged in with developer account

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to use the Facebook JS API to post to the users feed. A working example of what I wish to achieve is here: http://jsbin.com/utowek/2/edit?html,css,output

When I copy the code from the link above and use it on my server with my APP ID it works fine when I'm logged in to facebook with my developer account, but fails when I am not logged in or are logged in with a different account. When it fails I get the message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.'

In the app settings the Site URL is set to the html page on my server and the domain is set to my domain ending .co.uk

Comment: Have you taken the app live?

Comment: No - I wanted to be sure it worked first

Comment: It will not work until you take it live